# Gitlab CI/CD pipeline on server with custom port not working

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, pipeline, continuous-deployment, cicd

Yesterday, I have started setup of Gitlab CI-CD pipeline.
at beginning i have setup gitlab runner,
then i create test ci/cd pipeline & test successfully.

to extend this i have setuping whole deployment structure where
I'm login OCI instance & done all required stuff

but there facing some issue while connecting to oci instance throw gitlab ci/cd pipeline

I have OCI instance with custom port that not working
getting error as

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname <server_ip>:<server_port>: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Answer (score 1):

To Solve this I have modified, gitlab-ci.yml file
where @ time connecting server

```
ssh -p <server_port> <username>@<server_ip>
```

below is .gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
  TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest
  TAG_COMMIT: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA

stages:  
  - build
  - test
  - publish
  - deploy

build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Compiling the code..."
    - echo "Compile complete."

unit-test-job: 
  stage: test 
  script:
    - echo "Test Job Run & Done."

lint-test-job: 
  stage: test 
  script:
    - echo "No lint issues found."

publish:
#   image: docker:latest
  stage: publish
  services:
    # - docker:dind
  script:
    # - docker build -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST .
    # - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    # - docker push $TAG_COMMIT
    # - docker push $TAG_LATEST
    - echo "publishing code... This will take about 10 seconds."
    # - sleep 10
    - echo "No publishing issues found."


deploy-job:      # This job runs in the deploy stage.
  image: alpine:latest
  stage: deploy  # It only runs when *both* jobs in the test stage complete successfully.
  environment: production
  script:
    - chmod og= $ID_RSA
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -p $SSH_PORT $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "pwd"
    - echo "Deploying application..."
    - echo "Application successfully deployed."
```

*ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -p $SSH_PORT $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP "pwd"*